# Increasing the life of access token in facebook to directly integrate it with python facebook-sdk, without having any app-id and app-secret

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i was trying to develop this gist https://gist.github.com/krishnachaitanya9/62f6ce5f8fd948933977#file-facebook_notification I am using Python-sdk to code facebook Graph-API. I am using Access token but it expires in one hour. i have read to increase the life of access token from here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens but to extend the life of access token its asking for app-id and app-secret. As i didn't create any app in facebook is there any other method to increase the life of access token ?

Answer (score 0):

No.

This github project need your app access token, witch means you need to create a developer account and create an app.

Comment: thanks Guillaume Beauvois. can you please suggest any other method for authenticating to facebook to use with python-sdk other than access tokens?

Comment: There is none – authenticating against the API is done via an access token and nothing else. Now go ahead already and create an app yourself in the developer section – discussing this any further here in this way doesn’t make any sense.

Comment: CBroe, yup created an app and got access token for two months as you said. Thanks